# GeoServer layer will not display In QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver

I've just installed GeoServer, all the demo layers work fine in QGIS, but when I add my own shapefiles they result in an error message:

> Layer  1m-contours HT2_B1: Download of features for layer ne: 1m-contours HT2_B1 failed or partially failed: WFS exception report (code=NoApplicableCode text=java.lang.RuntimeException: org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.). You may attempt reloading the layer with F5

I can view the layer fine from the GeoServer Admin page fine.

Any ideas?

Looking into this more and when displayed using WMS the layers display as expected, weird.

Comment: You need to add more details. You are trying to publish the layer as a WFS layer? Does your shapefile have some non-ascii characters like åäö? Are you using the standard polygon style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space in your layer name `ne: 1m-contours HT2_B1` which makes it an invalid layer name so QGis is unable to parse it.

Edit your layer's name to replace   with (say) `_` and all will be well.

Comment: That was it, I didn't think that was the problem as other layers had spaces, however looking more closely the data sources referenced all use the underscore.